# Need to login from Java Application with Azure AD Credentials via Keyclock

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I already successfully integrated Azure Active Directory with Keyclock using Identity Providers(Microsoft)
[image]

With my existing JAVA Application, im able to login with the Keyclock users.

Now my requirement is, After successfully integrated Azure Active Directory with Keyclock using Identity Providers(Microsoft), i should be able to login with Azure AD users with the same login page.

Can you please help here. Thanks you

Below one is the my login page

[image]

Comment: The AAD login button doesn't appear in your application? Can you share a screenshot of how your login page is like when you click on sign in?

Comment: sure @AllenWu,
I added in the description. I  have to login Azure using "Azure Active Directory" button

Comment: Yes. You have to login Azure using "Azure Active Directory" button. The default login button is for Keyclock users.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.

You have to login Azure using "Azure Active Directory" button. The default login button is for Keyclock users.

You can refer to this [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYF-NLHD2uQ).